# OCR only image on one side

Tags: image, image-processing, ocr, preprocessor

I was wondering if there's a way to only OCR the document on the right (ignoring the left) without having to split the images in PS or any other image editor?

The problem is that sometimes there is text on the images. However, they are polluting my results as I only need to rear the right-hand side.

[image]

Kind regards, 
O.

```
## PREPROCESSING (load and read images to OCR and transform them into a DataFrame)

import pytesseract as tess
from tesserocr import PyTessBaseAPI, RIL
import os
from PIL import Image
import pandas as pd
import re
import tesserocr

path = "/Users/oliviervandhuynslager/PycharmProjects/Design Centre/assets/img/" ##path to directory (folder) where the images are located

count = 0
fileName = [] #create empty list that will contain the original filenames
fullText = [] #create empty list to store the OCR results per file
for imageName in os.listdir(path):
    count = count + 1
    fileName.append(imageName)
    # fileName.sort()#generate list from texts.

with PyTessBaseAPI(lang='eng') as api:
    for imageName in os.listdir(path):
        inputPath = os.path.join(path, imageName)
        api.SetImageFile(inputPath)
        text = api.GetUTF8Text()
        print(api.AllWordConfidences())
        fullText.append(text)

d = {"FILENAME":fileName, "OCR": fullText}
df = pd.DataFrame(d)

##Generate empty lists

search_material = []
search_product = []
search_manufacturer = []
search_designer = []
search_description = []
search_dimensions = []
search_packing = []
search_price = []
search_delivery = []

## -_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-

count_material = 0
count_product = 0
count_maufacturer = 0
count_designer = 0
count_description = 0
count_dimension = 0
count_packing = 0
count_price = 0

## search for PRODUCT (NAME/TITLE)
for values in df["OCR"]:
    try:
        search_product.append((re.search(r'Product[\s\S]+', values).group()).split("\n")[0].split(":")[1])
        count_product = count_product + 1
    except:
        search_product.append("")
df["PRODUCT"] = search_product

## search for MANUFACTURER
for values in df["OCR"]:
    try:
        search_manufacturer.append((re.search(r'Manufacturer[\S\s]+', values).group()).split("\n")[0].split(":")[1])
        count_maufacturer = count_maufacturer + 1
    except:
        search_manufacturer.append("")
df["MANUFACTURER"] = search_manufacturer

## search for DESIGNER
for values in df["OCR"]:
    try:
        search_designer.append((re.search(r'Designer[\S\s]+', values).group()).split("\n")[0].lstrip().split(":")[1])
        count_designer = count_designer + 1
    except:
        search_designer.append("")
df["DESIGNER"] = search_designer

## search for MATERIALS
for values in df["OCR"]:
    try:
        search_material.append((re.search(r'Material[\S\s]+', values).group()).split("\n")[0].lstrip().split(":")[1])
        count_material = count_material + 1
    except:
        search_material.append("")
df["MATERIAL"] = search_material

#search for DESCRIPTION:
for values in df["OCR"]:
    try:
        search_description.append((re.search(r'Description[\S\s]+', values).group()).split(":")[1])
        count_description = count_description + 1
    except:
        search_description.append("")
df["DESCRIPTION"] = search_description

#search for DIMENSIONS
for values in df["OCR"]:
    try:
        search_dimensions.append((re.search(r'Dimensions[\S\s]+', values).group()).split("\n")[0].split(":")[1])
        count_dimension = count_dimension + 1
    except:
        search_dimensions.append("")
df["DIMENSIONS"] = search_dimensions

#search for PACKING
for values in df["OCR"]:
    try:
        search_packing.append((re.search(r'Packing[\S\s]+', values).group()).split('\n\n')[0].split(":")[1])
        count_packing = count_packing + 1
    except:
        search_packing.append("")
df["PACKING"] = search_packing

#search for PRICE
for values in df["OCR"]:
    try:
        search_price.append((re.search(r'Price[\S\s]+', values).group()).split("\n")[0].split(":")[1])
        count_price = count_price + 1
    except:
        search_price.append("")
df["PRICE"] = search_price

#search for DELIVERY DAYS
for values in df["OCR"]:
    try:
        search_delivery.append((re.search(r'Delivery[\S\s]+', values).group()).split("\n\n")[0].split(":")[1])
        count_delivery = count_delivery + 1
    except:
        search_delivery.append("")
df["DELIVERY"] = search_delivery

df.drop(columns="OCR", inplace=True)

print(df)
```

Answer (score 1):

If the layout of text on your image is fixed then you can simply read the full Image but pass only half of that image array to tesseract.

```py
    import cv2

    img = cv2.imread(inputPath)
    _, width, _ = img.shape
    half = width//2
    cut = img[: half: , :]
    temp_path = r'path/where/you/want/your/cropped/image/to/be/saved'
    cv2.imwrite(temp_path, cut)
    api.SetImageFile(inputPath)
    text = api.GetUTF8Text()
    print(api.AllWordConfidences())
    fullText.append(text)
    os.remove(temp_path) #removing cut image from the directory
```

**Alternate Approach**
You can pass the image array `cut` to the tesseract instead of saving it and then removing it. In that case, remember to convert the image array `cut` to RGB format since open cv uses BGR format by default while reading images.

```py
rgb_arr = cv2.cvtColor(cut, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
```

---

All these things can be done with `PIL` also. In PIL you can use [crop()](https://effbot.org/imagingbook/image.htm#tag-Image.Image.crop) to extract the required part of the image. Also by default, it reads images in the RGB format and can be passed directly to tesseract if you are following the alternate approach as mentioned above

Answer (score 0):

You can call `api.SetRectangle` method passing the coordinates of the right half before recognition.